# Is there a performance difference between adding a .indexOn security rule and not adding one?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
{
    1:{
        status:"inactive"
    },
    2:{
        status:"inactive"
    },
    3:{
        status:"active"
    }
}
```

Here is an example JSON structure. My question is if I do:

```
return mainDB.ref("products").orderByChild('status').equalTo('inactive').once('value').then(data =>{
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
})
```

Is there a performance difference between adding a .indexOn security rule and not adding one, and also if .indexOn was added then where and when does it actually get filtered if not on the client?

Thank you!

Comment: Read about indexed queries in the documentation.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data

Answer (score 0):

If you perform a query on a property for which you've defined no index, Firebase will download all data from the location to the client, and perform the sorting and filtering there.

This means you should **always** define indexes for properties that you query on, which is why Firebase shows a pretty loud message in your JavaScript console when it finds you querying a property without an index.

---

**Update** for question in comments.

To create an index for the property `status` of each child node under a top-level node called `products` you'll need:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "products": {
      ".indexOn": "status"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yup! I totally see that console log. I've been trying to figure out how to create an indexOn for string values. So for the example above, how would I create a query for status' that are "active". And when I do create the query, what would happen if I try to read the data with "inactive"

Comment: That's a different question than you posted. Did you read the link that Doug gave you in his comment? Because that gives some pretty good examples of how to add indexes for your data. If you're having trouble making them work for you, edit your question to show what you've already tried.